# Access and modify Features

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I have some problems for get and set properties in my features.

When I try get some property with

```
feature.get('property')
```

It not working. I have to look inside to the object and take the property like this:

```
feature["O"]["features"]["0"]["O"]["carrier"]
```

But it is not a good way, because when I changed CDN to archives in my app, the object is different. And, obviously, feature.get('') must work.

Also, when I try to set new properties to some feature.

```
var feature = map.getLayers().item(1).getSource().getFeatureById(id);
feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point( ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') ));
```

It not working either.

Maybe the two mistakes are connected. And I suspect that it is for Cluster. It is the function when I create the Layer.

```
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: iconFeatures //add an array of features
  });

  var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
      source: vectorSource,
      distance: 40
  });

  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
       // source : vectorSource,
      source: clusterSource,
      style: clusterStyle
      });

    if (vector) {
      map.removeLayer(vector);
     }
     vector = vectorLayer;


      map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting feature directly from the source:

```
var feature = vectorSource.getFeatureById(id);
```

or

```
var feature = clusterSource.getFeatureById(id);
```